# Show layer navigation on search result 2-column-right.phtml page in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on custom Magento theme.On search result page when i set root template = page/2columns-right.phtml then layer navigation not showing when i changed it page/2columns-left.phtml then layer navigation showing.
Layer navigation showing on category page but not showing on search result page. 
any solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<reference name="left_first">` Used only in rwd themes.If your theme is based on it then you are able to change it, otherwise this reference not exist in base theme.
You can get help from here ->>>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838445/how-can-i-move-magentos-layered-navigation-block-from-left-column-to-right-colu

Comment: I was looking in base theme i very new in Magento

Answer (score 1):

You will need to re position the layered nav via xml by unsetting the block and inserting into the right structural block

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <catalogsearch_result_index>
            <reference name="left">
                <action method="unsetChild"><alias>catalog.leftnav</alias></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="right">
                <action method="insert"><blockName>catalog.leftnav</blockName></action>
            </reference>
        </catalogsearch_result_index>
    </layout>
```

Comment: Layer navigation showing on category page but not showing on search result page.

Comment: Sorry wrong xml selector should be "catalogsearch_result_index" I have updated answer

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: Have you added the above to your local.xml file and than also cleared magento cache

Answer (score 1):

copy catalogsearch.xml in your theme change

```
<reference name="left_first">
```

line to

```
<reference name="right">
```